# Drupal login not working

Tags: php, drupal, session, cookies

I tried to log in to a clients drupal installation today, and it seems like the log in doesn't "stick". The page does not give an error, and it looks like the session cookies are accurately set. I tried logging into the www version and without the www , still not working. My password is not incorrect, I just can't get into the site. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can use forget password link. this will create a new password for you that you can change after login

Comment: I tried it, it sent me the email, and clicked the link and it took me to a page with a log in button, i clicked that and was taken to /user, not logged in

Comment: it would be something like user/100 where 100 or else is your userid

Comment: yep, it only shows how long i have been member and nothing else.

Comment: Is there edit tab beside view tab, top of your display name? if it is there then it means that you are a registered user and currently logged in who can edit their account information. I also want to know what role you have been given for this site. Are you admin or just authenticated user?

Comment: In the database's `users` table is there a record for anonymous user (A record with `uid=0` and no other data)?

Comment: @VikasNaranje: I am super user, uid = 1;

Comment: @Clive: doing a select on users for uid 0 yields either empty data, 0, or NULL in all columns. And the row does exist.

Comment: @bmarti44: Can you confirm this is happening in multiple browsers? There was a known issue with IE7 at one point

Comment: @Clive: i have tried firefox 7 and chrome 14 (both with all caches completely cleared). Still not working.

Comment: I'm stumped, try this link: http://groups.drupal.org/node/21815

Comment: @Clive: I just found this in my database -> /sessions' is marked as crashed and should be repaired . this is regarding the sessions table. Do you know where I can find the create table command for sessions?

Comment: @Clive: OMG finally fixed it with a mysql command -> repair table sessions;

Comment: @bmarti44: Glad to hear you got it sorted :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the solution to my problem was the sessions table was corrupted. Running the mysql command

```
repair table sessions;
```

fixed the problem.